# Python: 1d array circular convolution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, convolution

I wonder if there's a function in numpy/scipy for 1d array circular convolution. The [`scipy.signal.convolve()` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html) only provides "mode" but not "boundary", while the `signal.convolve2d()` function needs 2d array as input.

I need to do this to compare open vs circular convolution as part of a time series homework.

Comment: Have you tried [``scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve1d``](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve1d.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve1d)? This offers more options on modes like ``wrap`` (which is basically circular) but only if the kernel is "big enough".

Comment: update: `convolve1d` is now just [`scipy.ndimage.convolve1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve1d.html#scipy.ndimage.convolve1d) and it is very fast

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since this is for homework, I'm leaving out a few details.

By the [definition of convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Definition), if you append a signal *a* to itself, then the convolution between *aa* and *b* will contain inside the cyclic convolution of *a* and *b*.

E.g., consider the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

%pylab inline

a = np.array([1] * 10)
b = np.array([1] * 10)

plot(signal.convolve(a, b));
```

[image]

That is the standard convolution. Now this, however

```
plot(signal.convolve(a, np.concatenate((b, b))));
```

[image]

In this last figure, try to see where is the result of the circular convolution, and how to generalize this.

Answer (score 16):

By convolution theorem, you can use Fourier Transform to get circular convolution.

```
import numpy as np
def conv_circ( signal, ker ):
    '''
        signal: real 1D array
        ker: real 1D array
        signal and ker must have same shape
    '''
    return np.real(np.fft.ifft( np.fft.fft(signal)*np.fft.fft(ker) ))
```

Comment: this is much faster than the other method using `scipy.signal.convolve` on my PC... not sure what the drawback is, but I like it.

Comment: Can you please tell me what does 'ker' means in theory ? I assume this is another signal .

Comment: This serves exactly the purpose of the question.

Comment: @Yunus, it is an abbreviation for "kernel," which stands for the object you slide over the signal.

Answer (score 6):

Code for this that you can copy-paste, in the spirit of StackOverflow:

```
n = a.shape[0]
np.convolve(np.tile(a, 2), b)[n:2 * n]
```

This assumes that a, b have the same shape.