# NumPy Convolution Theorem

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft, convolution

I am new to convolution and would therefore like to prove convolution theorem to myself by convolving two 1D signals together using FFT. However, my code is not consistent with the result obtained from `np.convolve`.

I have used the naive implementation from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474078/python-1d-array-circular-convolution):

```
import numpy as np

def Convolution(array,kernel):
    return np.real(np.fft.ifft( np.fft.fft(array)*np.fft.fft(kernel) ))

 a_flat = [ 1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 4., 5., 6., 0., 0. , 7.,  8.,  9.]
 k_flat = [ 1,2 ,1 ,0,0 ,0 ,0,0 ,0 ,0,-1,-2,-1]

 my_convolution = Convolution(a_flat, k_flat)
 np_convolution = np.convolve(a_flat, k_flat)

 print(my_convolution)
 print("") 
 print(np_convolution)
```

The output reads:

```
[ 19.  10.   4.  -5. -17. -13.   7.  13.  -5. -26. -20.   9.  24.]

[  1.   4.   8.   8.   3.   4.  13.  20.  17.   6.   6.  18.  24.  18.   6.  -4. -13. -20. -17.  -6.  -7. -22. -32. -26.  -9.]
```

I am clearly missing something. Can someone point me to my oversight?

Comment: You’re doing circular convolution in your own implementation - you’ll need to pad with zeroes to get proper convolution. (Or have I got it the wrong way round, and you actually want circular convolution in both cases ?)

Comment: To elaborate on Paul's answers, you can find a similar question/answer to yours here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/38066-difference-between-conv-ifft-fft-when-doing-convolution

The code is in matlab, but the reasoning is the same :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @hotpaw2 said. Always better to graph it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
%matplotlib inline

def Convolution(array,kernel):
    return np.real(np.fft.ifft( np.fft.fft(array)*np.fft.fft(kernel) ))

a_flat = [ 1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 4., 5., 6., 0., 0. , 7.,  8.,  9.]
k_flat = [ 1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-2,-1]

a_flat= np.pad(a_flat, (25, 25), 'constant', constant_values=(0, 0)).tolist()
k_flat= np.pad(k_flat, (25, 25), 'constant', constant_values=(0, 0)).tolist()


my_convolution = Convolution(a_flat, k_flat)
np_convolution = np.convolve(a_flat, k_flat)

fig,ax = p.subplots(3,figsize=(12,5))     

ax[0].plot(a_flat)
ax[1].plot(k_flat)
ax[2].plot(np.roll(my_convolution, 30),'.-',lw=0.5,label='myconv');  # arbitrary shift here
ax[2].plot(np.roll(np_convolution,  0),'.-',lw=3,alpha=0.3,label='npconv');
p.legend()
```

Nice example, btw.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of where your anchor is in your kernel, usually it's the median, in your case the 0 in the middle, you should still ensure it's correct.
Referring to @Paul R 's answer, make up your mind what kind of padding you want to use (zero padding, replicate the border regions, etc.) as this will influence your output.

Answer (score 1):

The result of a convolution is N+M-1, e.g. longer than either of the inputs.  So your FFT needs to be that long or longer.

An FFT/IFFT will wrap the fast convolution result around, and mix it up into a circular convolution.  But if you pad the data with lots of zeros on the end(s), the mix will be easy to unmix.